# Enable pagination in Responsive Filemanager 9

Tags: pagination, file-manager

Im currently developing a CMS that has Responsive filemanager 9 installed but i cant find where i enable the pagination in the file manager i already uploaded over 4k photos and all of them are in the same page.

How i can enable this?

Thanks

Comment: It does not seem that Responsive Filemanager 9 supports pagination

Answer (score 0):

> include 'pagination.class.php';
>   //https://github.com/lotsofcode/php-array-pagination/blob/master/pagination.class.php
>
> .numbers {
>      display: inline-block;
>     width:100%;
>   }
>
> .numbers a {
>      color: black;
>      float: left;
>      padding: 8px 16px;
>      text-decoration: none;
>   }
>
> .numbers a.selected {
>      background-color: #4CAF50;
>      color: white;
>      border-radius: 5px;
>   }
>
> .numbers a:hover:not(.selected) {
>      background-color: #ddd;
>      border-radius: 5px;
>   }
>
> //after $jplayer_ext=array("mp4","flv","webmv","webma","webm","m4a","m4v","ogv","oga","mp3","midi","mid","ogg","wav");
>
> $pagination = new pagination($files, (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1), 504);
>
> ```
> $files = $pagination->getResults();
> echo $pageNumbers = '<div class="numbers" >'.$pagination->getLinks().'</div><br>';
> ```